# hamburger menu only for mobile

Tags: javascript, css

My desktop menu view is perfect now I want to fix hamburger menu only for mobile version only; how can I add hamburger menu with CSS and JavaScript?

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>menu 1</title>
</head>
<div class="navbar-mega">
  <div class="dropdown-mega">
    <button class="dropbtn-mega" style="padding-top: 6px;padding-bottom: 0px;"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-home"
                            aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown-mega">

    <button class="dropbtn-mega"> Footwear</button>

    <div class="dropdown-content-mega">
      <div class="row-mega">
        <div class="column-mega">
          <h3>Shoes</h3>
          <a href="">Casual Shoes</a>
          <a href="">Sneaker &amp; Sports Shoes</a>
          <a href="">Formal &amp; Party Shoes</a>
          <a href="">School Shoes</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column-mega">
          <h3>Sandals</h3>
          <a href="">Clogs </a>
          <a href="">Sandal</a>
          <a href="">Flip Flop</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column-mega">
          <h3>Socks</h3>
          <a href="">Newborn Socks</a>
          <a href="">Regular Socks </a>
          <a href="">School Socks</a>
          <a href="">Fashion Socks</a>
          <a href="">Stocking &amp; Tights</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column-mega">
          <h3>Sock Shoes</h3>
          <a href="">Booties</a>
          <a href="">Rubber Soles Sock Shoes</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column-mega">
          <img width="300px" src="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hamburger">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<body>

</body>

</html>
javascriptcssEdit tags
```

Comment: show us what you tried so far please

Comment: Where's the CSS for your "perfect" menu to show where you are, currently? Where's your (best) attempt at creating a hamburger menu for mobile?

Comment: toggle icon showing but menu not showing

Answer (score 0):

First, hide the hamburger menu and display it just on mobile devices:

```
.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: .navbar-mega {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #73499d;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.navbar-mega a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-mega {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.hamburger {
    display: none;
}

Comment: hamburger icon is working but when click nothing show\

Comment: You need JS to hide/display it. It would be better to google how to develop hamburger menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use @media for show/hide with width mobile

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hamburger {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.hamburger span {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 2px;
    height: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>menu 1</title>
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="navbar-mega">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-mega">
    <button class="dropbtn-mega" style="padding-top: 6px;padding-bottom: 0px;">
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown-mega">

    <button class="dropbtn-mega"> Footwear</button>

    <div class="dropdown-content-mega">
      <div class="row-mega">
        <div class="column-mega">
          <h3>Shoes</h3>
          <a href="">Casual Shoes</a>
          <a href="">Sneaker &amp; Sports Shoes</a>
          <a href="">Formal &amp; Party Shoes</a>
          <a href="">School Shoes</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column-mega">
          <h3>Sandals</h3>
          <a href="">Clogs </a>
          <a href="">Sandal</a>
          <a href="">Flip Flop</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column-mega">
          <h3>Socks</h3>
          <a href="">Newborn Socks</a>
          <a href="">Regular Socks </a>
          <a href="">School Socks</a>
          <a href="">Fashion Socks</a>
          <a href="">Stocking &amp; Tights</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column-mega">
          <h3>Sock Shoes</h3>
          <a href="">Booties</a>
          <a href="">Rubber Soles Sock Shoes</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column-mega">
          <img width="300px" src="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).